# How to import XML file structure for complex data into Mysql database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Hello i want to import xml data to Mysql database in PHP.Can any one help me on creating data structure of it and how should i import it in mysql database using php.

Link for xml structure is : [xml](https://www.service-architecture.com/articles/object-oriented-databases/xml_file_for_complex_data.html)

I have created databse structure like product (product_id, description, product_image) ,catalog_item (catalog_item_id, product_id, gender, item_number, price), size(size_id, catalog_item_id, description) color_swatch (color_swatch_id, size_id, image, description)

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog>
   <product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <catalog_item gender="Men's">
         <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
         <price>39.95</price>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
      <catalog_item gender="Women's">
         <item_number>RRX9856</item_number>
         <price>42.50</price>
         <size description="Small">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Extra Large">
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
   </product>
</catalog>
```

Comment: Please add anything you have so far, database design any code etc.  People on SO will help if you have problems.

Comment: I have created databse structure like product (product_id, description, product_image) ,catalog_item (catalog_item_id, product_id, gender, item_number, price), size(size_id, catalog_item_id, description) color_swatch (color_swatch_id, size_id, image, description)   i dont know it is correct Or not